# How can I use initial letters on selectize.js

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

Is there a way to configure selectize.js to fetch results based only on initial letters instead of contextual search?

[image: Like this]

Comment: What do you mean? Disable mid word matching?

Comment: @basher I want to show just initial letters result, like this [link](http://imgur.com/HCEc6ma)

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a better way, but this will definitely do it for you. First off, use a local copy of selectize rather than a cdn. Then change the following line in sifter:

```
var scoreValue = function(value, token) {
    var score, pos;

    if (!value) return 0;
    value = String(value || '');
    pos = value.search(token.regex);
    if (pos === -1) return 0;
    score = 0; //This line got changed.
    if (pos === 0) score += 0.5;
    return score;
};
```

[Here's a link to the line in github](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js#L140)

Comment: I tried but it is not worked. Do you have a working copy? http://codepen.io/mrsarac/pen/JdgBRX

Comment: @Disconnect try my update. It works in your codepen now.

Comment: @Disconnect note i used a local, modified version of selectize rather than a CDN which is what you were doing in the codepen...